# How to run "npm run dev" command on my hosted Laravel website on Hostinger?

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I have created a website with authentication using Laravel "composer requires laravel/ui and php artisan ui vue --auth"

After deploying the project to Hostinger, the framework authentication design is not showing properly. Maybe I need to run the "npm run dev" command. How can I do this on my live server on Hostinger?

[Structure not showing + error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLabE.png)

I tried to find the specific solution but failed.

Comment: You’ll probably need to ssh into your server and run `npm run build`.